# angular: how to handle async pipes correctly

Tags: angular, asynchronous, angular2-observables, rxjs-observables

I would like to display all users  after all controls were added to the ProfileForm. That´s why I tried using the async pipe on my observable users$. But obviously it displays the users before all controls were added and not after. How do I wait until all controls are added?

ts:

```
profileForm = this.fb.group({
    name: []
});

users$: Observable<Users[]>;


ngOnInit(): void {
    this.users$ = this.userService.getAllUsers();

    this.users$.forEach(user =>
        this.profileForm.addControl(`user_${user.id}`, this.fb.control(id));
    );
}
```

html:

```
<mat-expansion-panel *ngFor="let user of users$ | async">
    <mat-expansion-panel-header>
        <mat-panel-title>
            <mat-checkbox [formControlName]="'user_' + user.id"></mat-checkbox>
            <span>{{ user.name }}</span>         
        </mat-panel-title>
    </mat-expansion-panel-header>
</mat-expansion-panel>
```

Comment: Can I see the inside of getAllUsers method as well?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can do it like this:

```
this.users$ = this.userService.getAllUsers().pipe(
   tap(users => {
        users.forEach(user =>
        this.profileForm.addControl(`user_${user.id}`, this.fb.control(id));
    );
   })
  );
```

Comment: Bonus: if `this.users$ = this.userService.getAllUsers()` is ever changed to an observable that emits a new array of users whenever `this.userService.refreshUsers()` is called, this answer will not need modification, but `Observable.forEach` (used in the question) will have issues.